# auto login Linux 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, auto-login

i installed a minimal ISO of Ubuntu on my virtual machine . after installing i installed these programs :

```
open-box
lightdm
```

everything works fine but when i want to do the auto login ,i get stuck . i have read many forms and watched a lot of videos,consequently found ways but none of them works for me the one that i'm eager to work with is lightdm.conf file :

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

in the file first thing i did was to delete the guess and it worked fine but the rest of the code dose not work at all

```
[SeatDefaults] 
allow-guest=false
autologin-user=saeed
autologin-user-timeout=0
user-session=ubuntu
```

since i am not using unity i did not write(but i did try the code before) this code:

```
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

saeed is my only user now , however i did try making another and auto login with it but the result was unsatisfying.

it's been around 12 hours of searching and trying ,it seems that everybody are getting the result but i keep getting the login screen since . i am working on an embedded device therefor it is crucial to get rid of the login in the main device(server), nevertheless i do need the password for SSH connections security .

your help is appreciated in advance

Comment: This is an old post, but suprisingly nobody noted that **SSH password authentication shouldn't be used if it's intended to be secure**. A trusted public key should be added to the machine instead which would then be used by clients to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

I set auto-login when I installed Ubuntu 16.04.3. What in my /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf is:

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=jpx
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Where "jpx" is my username. This may help you.